# php: is there a reason to first fill a result array before echoing the data

Tags: php, sql

I'm reading sitepoint's book **PHP & MySQL Novice to Ninja** and I'm wondering why he takes an extra step.

My SQL query is

```
try
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM trazooevents WHERE county = :county';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':county', $_POST['search_term']);
    $s->execute();

    include 'events.inc.php';
}
```

and in my include

```
<?php foreach ($s as $row): ?>
    <li class="db-headline"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['eventname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></li>
    // etc.
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and it works perfectly fine.
In the book **Kevin Yank** adds an extra step similar to:

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $events[] = array(
    'eventname' => $row['eventname'],
    'eventdetails' => $row['eventdetails'],
    'weburl' => $row['weburl'],
    'imagename' => $row['imagename'],
    'expireson' => $row['expireson']
    );
}
```

Does he do this to just get an index label or is there some security issue I don't know?

Comment: Probably that's to keep lazy people who do `select *` from flooding their server's memory while fetching fields they'll never use. It could just as easily be `$events[] = $row;`, but this copies only fields you know you'll need.

Comment: lol thanks for the lazy dig :P 
I'll change it of course for release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of readability of the code. You won't use row but an array with more semantic significance: events.

Answer (score 1):

It is just to get the index label.. not necessary though.. :)

Comment: He can just use fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) or fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) method for index labels